# What will be the socket behavior if program is stopped at break point?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, posix

Here is the scenario:

I have a select based socket server in Linux which processes single packet a time. Lets say several packets are coming at high speed and I hit a break point while my process is at processing stage of current packet. My question is that what will happen to packets that are being sent to my server process non stop and while it is stopped at a break point. Will they get dropped? or Will OS buffer these packets and deliver to my process when it comes out of break point?

Though I have some idea but I want to confirm it from gurus here and probably I will learn more about socket behavior.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could easily try this... why ask here and wait hours (or days) for an answer when you could answer your own question in a few minutes?

Comment: I get answer here in matter of minutes. Thats a wonderful thing about stackoverflow. Any way as I said, I might get to learn new things  or what happens behind the scenes while discussing here. Knowledge is never a complete thing.

Comment: Regardless, the ability to research your own problems is one of a developer's most important tools.  Try the experiment then ask questions about what you don't understand.  In the long run you will get more out of it.

Comment: I wonder what the difference is between the program being stopped on a break point, and the program being very slow, or busy dong other things, or being swapped out and denied CPU time, or any other reason for taking a long time between socket reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incoming packets will be queued up by the OS kernel until its buffer gets full. Any more packets will simply be dropped, but depending on the type of connection the kernel may signal the other end to stop sending (TCP aka SOCK_STREAM should, UDP aka SOCK_DGRAM probably won't). The *sender* should be prepared to handle this scenario.

How big the buffer is depends on the system; you may be able to query the size and/or change it (how this is done is usually OS dependent).

It doesn't matter if your process is halted for debugging, just slow, busy waiting for other events or being swapping in; if it does not read the data from the socket it will be queued.

Comment: TCP *will* signal the other end to stop sending, and the peer application doesn't have to do anything about that at all, unless it using non-blocking mode incorrectly. Querying and changing socket receive buffer sizes is not OS-dependent: it is done with get/setsockopt() and SO_RCVBUFSIZ on all platforms.